How can I utilise minimum scale factor before defaulting to multiple lines?
I am trying to have a string of text be displayed within my view with an adaptable size so that it works with all text sizes and only expands its parent view when absolutely necessary.
It seems at the moment the preference for text is to move it onto multiple lines, ignoring the minimum scale factor. When the text exceeds the bounds of the parent I want it to use the minimum scale factor and only when that exceeds the bounds of the parent should the text be split across multiple lines.
Below is an example of an attempt I made using ViewThatFits. Even though the minimum scale factor of 0.7 fits within the frame the ViewThatFits returns the multiline text instead.
struct AdaptiveText: View {
    
    var text: String
    let fontType: Font
    let fontWeight: Font.Weight

    var body: some View {
        
        ViewThatFits{
            //Shrinking Text
            Text(text)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
                .fontWeight(fontWeight)
                .font(fontType)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            //MultiLine Text
            Text(text)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
                .fontWeight(fontWeight)
                .font(fontType)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    AdaptiveText(text: "Hi, this is quite a big sentence I guess", fontType: .title, fontWeight: .medium)
        .border(.blue)
        .background(.red)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 85)
        .border(Color.red)
        .padding()
        .border(Color.red)
}

What is being returned from the view that fits is not the shrunk text but the multiline text

Even though it does fit within the parent

If this shrunk text didn't fit on one line like this

Thats when I'd like it to automatically be on as many lines as necessary, always attempting to shrink the text before moving to a new line.

Googling this doesn't provide much help, everything I have tried involving .fixedSize, .lineLimit, .minimumScaleFactor doesn't seem to work as I expect it to. Perhaps there is a method I am missing?
If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

A similar issue is addressed in SwiftUI: How can I limit a string to be displayed as one line, and support automatic scaling to a specified ratio, sliding to view the full text, except that the failover case uses a ScrollView, which has the same height as a single line of text. Still trying to think of a way of getting multi-line failover to work. Presumably, you also want maximum scaling (minimum size) for the failover too?

Yes so I would expect the size calculation to go 1.if full size text fits, 2. If minimum scale factor fits 3. Include an additional line and then repeat the steps. Reading the link I feel quite confused about using a scroll view to display text. I would like the parent view to be able to grow to fit larger multi line text but I just want the minimum scale factor to take priority over these new lines

The .minimumScaleFactor being applied to the first version will take effect if the height of the Text is constrained. So what we need to know, is the height of one line of text when scaled to fit.

The height of a scaled line can be found using a hidden version of the single-line text as a layer in a ZStack.

The height of the scaled single line can be read in an .onChange handler that monitors the height of a GeometryReader in a background layer. This way it adapts to size changes, such as if the orientation of the device is changed.

You confirmed that you want the failover case to use maximum scaling too (in other words, to have minimum size). The easiest way to achieve this is to set a smaller font size, computed as (maximum font size * minimum scaling factor).

In order to be able to scale the font size like this, we need to know the maximum font size. An easy way to solve this is to pass the font size as parameter to AdaptiveText, instead of the actual font.


AdaptiveText(text: "Hi, this is quite a big sentence I guess", fontSize: 28, fontWeight: .medium)
    // ...other modifiers as before

struct AdaptiveText: View {

    var text: String
    let fontSize: CGFloat
    let fontWeight: Font.Weight
    @State private var oneLineHeight: CGFloat? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize, weight: fontWeight))
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
                .hidden()
                .background {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: proxy.size.height, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                                oneLineHeight = newVal
                            }
                    }
                }
            ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: fontSize, weight: fontWeight))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
                    .frame(height: oneLineHeight)
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: fontSize * 0.7, weight: fontWeight))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}


